# how to read the cllocation data before the tableview data in the same view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want the cllocation parameter first in the app and then print it,and then want the talbe view content in the same viewcontroller file.

i am calling the startupdatinglocation in the initwithnibname and table view viewdidload but content of table view is coming first and then my value of cllocation in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and you shouldn't try.

Just call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in your delegate method where `CLLocation` is returned.